# Does a Cache refresh on one page affect all other pages?

Tags: css, caching, refresh

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere but two hours of searching has yielded nothing definitive.

If I force a cache refresh on a CSS file on my index page
will subsequent pages use the newly refreshed contents?

e.g.

Initial index.php:
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?v=1">`

.. main.css modified ...

index.php changed to:
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?v=2">`

news.html: (unchanged)
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">`

Answer (score 1):

For the unchanged it will not affect unless the cache is removed. If you remove the cache, it will take the latest one. For the rest i.e with changes, it shall take the latest irrespective of the cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 The browser will cache the file contents for a given URL, so when you don't change the URL to the css file on the news page, it will (likely) use the cached version.

Comment: Thanks Nathan - Just what I was hoping!

To clarify:

If a cached resource is refreshed with an updated version, then any subsequent reference to that resource will return the updated version.

Is that true for all browsers?

Comment: Yes @JohnMcKean . If you delete the cache and then refresh the page, all previous versions will be discarded and the latest one will take effect. It mostly works on all major browsers.